# http meta Refresh redirecting with web query params

Tags: html, http-headers, meta-tags, page-refresh, http-equiv

Is it possible to pass the web query parameters included in original web request (for example: `?id=123&topic=technology`) using meta `refresh` so the target web site (like in the following sample)

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://webinfocentral.com'"/>
```

will be able to read/parse that original web query params? If not, what could be the possible alternative(s) working in all major web browsers? Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?